# Paypal Subscription + Recurring Payment

Tags: paypal, subscription, recurring

I have some doubts regarding Paypal Subscription.
We are hosting a website and we would like to give a subscription feature to our customers.
We have implemented that with the sandbox subscription feature. It is working fine.
We would like to add one feature of discount to our customers.
According to that the customers with the discount offer can use the site for a certain period  with an discounted amount.After the discount period,the amount will be changed to regular amount. It requires the updation of regular amount after a certain period. The user will register the subscription first time only. After that the the subscription has to be modified to the regular amount without another user intervention. How can we update/modify subscription to change the regular amount after discount period, without disturbing the user.
Kindly help me on this..

Thanks..

Answer (score 6):

The CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API (accessible to both Express Checkout as well as Website Payments Pro users) as well as a regular subscription button (https://www.paypal.com/buttonfactory/) both support trial periods by in their design. Thus, you wouldn't need to modify/update the subscription.

For the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, simply pass along an INITAMT you want to be charged immediately, and set the STARTDATE to a date in the future when you want to have the actual recurring payment start.

For a subscription button, use the button generator, or pass the a1, t1 and p1 parameter respectively to add a trial period.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_CreateRecurringPayments
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI00JQU

If you still want to update a recurring payment and/or subscription, have a look at the UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile API.