# PayPal recurring donation amount (user-defined) option

Tags: paypal, recurring, user-defined

I see how to add a select box for pre-determined recurring donation/subscription amounts but can there also be an option for the user to decide how much they wish to donate (and perhaps how frequently)?

Thanks

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353738/paypal-subscription-recurring-payment?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

With Donate and Buy Now payment buttons your buyers can enter their own price to pay on the PayPal checkout page. You can accomplish that by just leaving the `amount` value empty.

Subscription buttons require that an amount (the `a3` variable for Subscriptions) value be provided during the redirect to PayPal so if you leave the field blank you would get an error. However, if you change the `a3` input type to be `text` instead of `hidden` in your HTML form buyers can enter the amount on a text field on your website before being redirected to PayPal.

Comment: This should be the right solution. Thanks! I will try this.